# How do I Select Data and Insert Data at the same time?

Tags: sql, asp.net

How do I select data from a table and populate it on a grid view then, insert the data to another table at the same time?

I am using an event, `OnTextchanged`.

`OnTextChanged`:

1.

```
select snum, itemname, desc
from item_tbl
```

2.

```
insert into detail
values snum, item, desc
left join item_tbl
where snum(of text box) = item_tbl.snum
```

Comment: Which database you are using

Comment: Do you need a sql query answer or asp.net answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `Output` clause to `select` the `inserted` rows, which helps you `insert` and `select` the rows at the same time.

```
INSERT INTO Insert_table
            (col1,col2..)
Output      inserted.col1,
            inserted.col2
            ....
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       ...
FROM   select_table
```

Comment: on txtchange
1.select snum,itemname,desc
from item_tbl

2. insert into detail
values snum,item,desc
left join item_tbl
where snum(of text box)=item_tbl.snum